# Bad Redis sunion performance with CM_Cache_Backend_Redis

Tags: performance, magento, redis

We have a Magento EE 1.14 situation with Redis caching in place that is giving us ongoing performance issues despite all the troubleshooting and best practice configurations we have applied.

The config for the cache and FPC is:

```
    <cache>
        <backend>Mage_Cache_Backend_Redis</backend>
        <backend_options>
            <server>127.0.0.1</server> <!-- or absolute path to unix socket -->
            <port>6379</port>
            <persistent>cache-db0</persistent> <!-- Specify a unique string like "cache-db0" to enable persistent connections. -->
            <database>0</database>
            <password></password>
            <force_standalone>0</force_standalone>  <!-- 0 for phpredis, 1 for standalone PHP -->
            <connect_retries>3</connect_retries>    <!-- Reduces errors due to random connection failures -->
            <read_timeout>20</read_timeout>         <!-- Set read timeout duration -->
            <automatic_cleaning_factor>0</automatic_cleaning_factor> <!-- Disabled by default -->
            <compress_data>1</compress_data>  <!-- 0-9 for compression level, recommended: 0 or 1 -->
            <compress_tags>1</compress_tags>  <!-- 0-9 for compression level, recommended: 0 or 1 -->
            <compress_threshold>20480</compress_threshold>  <!-- Strings below this size will not be compressed -->
            <compression_lib>gzip</compression_lib> <!-- Supports gzip, lzf and snappy -->
            <use_lua>0</use_lua> <!-- Set to 1 if Lua scripts should be used for some operations -->
        </backend_options>
    </cache>
    <full_page_cache>
        <backend>Mage_Cache_Backend_Redis</backend>
        <backend_options>
            <server>127.0.0.1</server> <!-- or absolute path to unix socket -->
            <port>6379</port>
            <persistent>cache-db2</persistent> <!-- Specify a unique string like "cache-db0" to enable persistent connections. -->
            <database>2</database> <!-- Separate database 2 to keep FPC separately -->
            <password></password>
            <force_standalone>0</force_standalone>  <!-- 0 for phpredis, 1 for standalone PHP -->
            <connect_retries>3</connect_retries>    <!-- Reduces errors due to random connection failures -->
            <lifetimelimit>57600</lifetimelimit>    <!-- 16 hours of lifetime for cache record -->
            <compress_data>0</compress_data>        <!-- DISABLE compression for EE FPC since it already uses compression -->
            <auto_expire_lifetime></auto_expire_lifetime> <!-- Force an expiry (Enterprise_PageCache will not set one) -->
            <auto_expire_refresh_on_load></auto_expire_refresh_on_load> <!-- Refresh keys when loaded (Keeps cache primed frequently requested resources) -->
        </backend_options>
    </full_page_cache>
```

In normal operation, Redis is behaving well and for the most part there are no problems however, the only time the site is experiencing issues is when a daily import task that updates product inventory and pricing is executed. Immediately after this, the Redis performance significantly deteriorates and on occasion produces Magento error reports with "read error on connection". This issue goes away when the garbage collection script is executed.

When analysing Redis operations, we notice that the sunion calls perform particularly poorly. Here are comparison stats between 2 Magento-Redis situations, the first is fine and the second is our problematic one:

Stats on a 'good' Magento/Redis server

```
used_memory_human:6.70G
instantaneous_ops_per_sec:155
db0:keys=43699,expires=7462,avg_ttl=27636661
db2:keys=6375,expires=6375,avg_ttl=47526572
db3:keys=68969,expires=18510,avg_ttl=75156076
cmdstat_hget:calls=3742856691,usec=27239921284,usec_per_call=7.28
*cmdstat_sunion:calls=806716,usec=160088795,usec_per_call=198.45
```

Stats on our problem situation:

```
used_memory_human:54.33M
instantaneous_ops_per_sec:269
db0:keys=3895,expires=988,avg_ttl=4073916
db2:keys=7875,expires=561,avg_ttl=18645058
db4:keys=101,expires=23,avg_ttl=6494711
db5:keys=591,expires=8,avg_ttl=65237814
cmdstat_hget:calls=35389067,usec=237642652,usec_per_call=6.72
*cmdstat_sunion:calls=14018,usec=517646874,usec_per_call=36927.30
```

You can see the average bad sunion performance: 36927.30 vs. 198.45 microseconds per call.

redis-cli info:

```
# Server
redis_version:3.2.8
redis_git_sha1:00000000
redis_git_dirty:0
redis_build_id:6ee7659e3cbceeef
redis_mode:standalone
os:Linux 3.13.0-107-generic x86_64
arch_bits:64
multiplexing_api:epoll
gcc_version:4.8.4
process_id:6267
run_id:b27c19a312f347b10e4afe68692ffa0d22613f1c
tcp_port:6379
uptime_in_seconds:182016
uptime_in_days:2
hz:20
lru_clock:12966704
```

Any ideas about what could possibly be causing this?

Comment: Your _bad_ redis instance seems to have much less memory allocated, are they supposed to have the same amount?

Comment: There is no memory allocation limit set in the redis.conf. The fact that the 'bad' instance struggles even with the low memory consumption of the DBs is even more puzzling, compared to the size on the other machine.

Comment: To clarify, the good and the bad nodes, do not show the same usage patterns. You can see that the DBs used, and the number of keys, are different. This seems to be a good clue as to where in the problem lies.

Comment: Specifically, what is in db/keyspace numbered 3, 4, and 5? Your config only shows 0 and 2 in use.

Comment: Thanks guys for trying to help. In the 'bad' instance,
db0=object cache - prod
db1=sessions cache - prod
db2=full page cache - prog
db3=sessions cache - stage
db4=object cache - stage
db5=full page cache - stage
The staging site is on the same server but is not used very frequently hence the low keycount.
In the end, this issue might not be due to any Redis config but possibly more to do with the data that Redis has to deal with. We have now found a strategy to work around this issue by changing some timings of the maintenance process during which this issue is exacerbated.